# Why is my component an instance of JRootPane if I never assigned it to one?

Tags: java, user-interface, jpanel, jdialog

Let me explain what my code does:
I have created my own class which extends a JDialog. This class, lets call it class A, contains a: JMenuBar, JMenu, JMenuItem, JButton, JDialog, JPanel and MouseAdapter. My project is very similar to the FreeCell Game, in which I am currently trying to move multiple images, which are in their own JPanels.
Right now, my issue is this: when the user clicks on something on the screen, I get the point coordinated of where they clicked and set a Component like

```
Component component = getComponentAt(point);
```

I then check to see if it is an instance of a JPanel, ie the card

```
if (component instanceof JPanel)
```

so I can move the card around. THIS is where my problem arrises. When I print out what my components class is, it states that it is a JRootPane, but I have never even used or seen this object in my entire life, until I looked it up just now. I would like to know why my component is an object of JRootPane when I never used use it.

No matter where I click on the screen, it keeps stating that my component is a JRootPane...

It it be because JRootPane contains JDialog? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JRootPane.html

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JRootPane.html Added to for instance a JFrame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It it be because JRootPane contains JDialog?

No a JRootPane doesn't contain a JDialog. A JDialog contains a JRootPanel.

> I would like to know why my component is an object of JRootPane when I never used use it.

```
Component component = getComponentAt(point);
```

So what Container does `getComponentAt(...)` refer to? Is it the dialog, or is it the panel?

In your case it looks like the `getComonentAt()` method is relative to the dialog and therefore will return the component relative to the dialog. Since the first component added to the dialog is a JRootPane it returns the root pane.

What you want to do is add the MouseListener to the panel that contains the images. Then in the MouseListener code you do:

```
@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
{
    Component parent = e.getComponent();  
    Component child = parent.getComponentAt(...);
}
```

Then if you click on a component containing an image you will get the component.